# DC.JS Scatter Plot not filtering

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I am a big fan of the [Dimensional Charting Javascript Library](http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/), but I am having an issue with the scatter plot feature.  This chart type does not seem to filter the same way other charts do.

Here is an example: 
[Fiddle of Scatter Plot](http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/m6ppf/)

When I filter the typeDimension, I can see the row chart gets filtered but the scatter plot does not.

```
    typeDimension.filter("foo");
    dc.redrawAll();
```

My expectation is that the scatter plot would update to show only the points that fit with the filter criteria.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!
- DJ

Comment: Probably related to https://github.com/NickQiZhu/dc.js/issues/491? I am too interested to know how to overcome this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened an issue at github.com/NickQiZhu/dc.js/issues/491.  The feedback is that the functionality to transition the scatterPlot points based on applied filters is not released yet.

I ended up using a bubbleChart instead and achieved what I needed.

I ended up overriding the MIN_RADIUS parameter however so that smaller bubbles could be displayed:

```
    bubbleChart.width(500)
        .height(200)
        .dimension(typeDimension)
        .group(typeGroup)
        .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 20]))
        .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1000]))
        .keyAccessor(function (d) {
        return d.value.count;
    })
        .valueAccessor(function (d) {
        return d.value.avgSpeed;
    })
        .radiusValueAccessor(function (d) {
        return 1;
    });
    bubbleChart.MIN_RADIUS = 1;
```

Here is a jsfiddle for using a bubblechart: http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/ymU5c/